# Servlet filter with a HttpServletResponseWrapper output an empty body - Wrong object used

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I try to implement a HttpServletResponseWrapper in order to read the content of a servlet response. I can successfully read to content in the filter. But the final packet which go out of the application has an empty body (check with browser and fiddler)

#### Implementation

```
class ReadableContentHttpServletResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream;
    private ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream;
    
    
    public ReadableContentHttpServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        servletOutputStream = new ServletOutputStream() {
            private WriteListener writeListener = null;
            
            
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {               
                outputStream.write(b);
                if (writeListener != null) {
                    writeListener.notify();
                }
            }
            
            @Override
            public void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener) {
                this.writeListener =  writeListener;
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public boolean isReady() {
                //ByteArrayOutputStream.close() has not effect 
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
    
    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        return new PrintWriter(outputStream);
    }
    
    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return servletOutputStream;     
    };
    
    //... Getters...    
}
```

#### The filter

```
...
ReadableContentHttpServletResponse wrappedResponse = new ReadableContentHttpServletResponse(httpResponse);
chain.doFilter(request,wrappedResponse);
log.debug("content = " + wrappedResponse.getContent()); //working
log.debug("content = " + wrappedResponse.getContent()); //working
```

I tried to read several time the `ByteArrayOutputStream` in the filter (which works) or not, but the final body's packet is still empty. I also tried with the `ByteArrayOutputStream` of apache.

Note that there is only one filter, and I removed everything that was coming after the `dofilter`.

EDIT: The stream used to generate the final packet is not the `ServletOutputStream` of the wrapper. It is the `ServletOutputStream`  of the original `HttpServletResponse response`.

**Why?** Sincethe wrapper overloads the `ServletResponse`methods and is given to `dofilter(..)`, it should use the stream returned by the wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outputStream used to generate the final packet is not the one in the the wrapper but the one in the original `ServletResponse` object (kept in super class `ServletResponseWrapper`). We just need to write to both stream.

*This behavior looks very strange to me since `dofilter` return the wrapper's reference. You are welcome if you have any explanation.*

The workaround:

```
class ReadableContentHttpServletResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream;
    private ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream;



    public ReadableContentHttpServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        super(response);

        outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final ServletOutputStream  responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

        servletOutputStream = new ServletOutputStream() {
            private WriteListener writeListener = null;


            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {               
                outputStream.write(b);
                responseOutputStream.write(b);
                if (writeListener != null) {
                    writeListener.notify();
                }
            }


...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's always the `ServletOutputStream` of the original `ServletResponse` that is used by the container in order to actually send anything to the client.

Let's assume there are three `Filter`s, *F1*, *F2* and *F3* in a particular `FilterChain` and that *F2* wishes to modify the data produced by whatever resource is at the end of the chain. Following events would in that case occur:

- *F1*'s `doFilter()` is invoked with instance *R* as the `ServletResponse` argument, which in turn holds a reference to `ServletOutputStream` *S*. *F1* calls `FilterChain.doFilter(..., R)`.
- *F2*'s `doFilter()` is as well invoked with *R* and *S*. Because *F2* wants to modify the response, it wraps *R* in an e.g. `HttpServletResponseWrapper` implementation *R'* providing a stand-in `ServletOutputStream` *S'*. *F2* calls `FilterChain.doFilter(..., R')`.
- *F3*'s `doFilter()` is thus invoked with arguments *R'* and *S'* and calls `FilterChain.doFilter(..., R').
- The resource targeted by the client's request writes data to *S'*.
- *F3*'s `doFilter()` returns.
- *F2* flushes *S'*, does something with its contents and writes the modified payload to *S*. It can't really do otherwise, unless it purposely wants *F1* -and ultimately the client- to receive an empty response. *F2*'s `doFilter() returns.
- *F1*'s doFilter() returns and the contents of *S* are written back to the client.